# Handling the Payumoney Response in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, payumoney

I have init the payumoney flow from a fragment and I am getting the response OnActivityResult in my Activity. but I need to update some values the after the response in fragment. there is any possible to get the response in fragment or get my custom objects from fragment to activity while getting  response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste your code that will be helpful

Comment: 'code' 
mPaymentParams = PayUPaymentUtil.getInstance().calculateServerSideHashAndInitiatePayment1(mPaymentParams);
        mPaymentParams = builder.build();
        PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(mPaymentParams, getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme_Green, false);
'code'

payumoney init from my payment fragment but I get response by onActivityResult in my Activity.
but I need to update payment object which is in fragment.

Comment: refer my answer

Comment: any code / any solution ? thank u sir

Answer (score 0):

You can do it since Activity gets the result of `onActivityResult()`, you will need to override the activity's `onActivityResult()` and call `super.onActivityResult()` to propagate to the respective fragment for unhandled results codes or for all.

Option 2:

An explicit call from fragment to the onActivityResult function is as follows.

In the parent Activity class, override the onActivityResult() method and even override the same in the Fragment class and call as the following code.

In the parent class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dualPane);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In the child class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // In fragment class callback
}
```

Comment: Android studio prompt me to write onActivityResult in fragment as public

Comment: write onActivityResult in activity and do nothing with itr also write onactivity result in fragment

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

If you're calling `startActivityForResult()` from the fragment then you should call `startActivityForResult()`, not `getActivity().startActivityForResult()`, as it will result in fragment `onActivityResult()`.

If you're not sure where you're calling on startActivityForResult() and how you will be calling methods.

**Option 2:**

Since Activity gets the result of `onActivityResult()`, you will need to override the activity's `onActivityResult()` and call `super.onActivityResult()` to propagate to the respective fragment for unhandled results codes or for all.

If above two options do not work, then refer to option 3 as it will definitely work.

**Option 3:**

An explicit call from fragment to the onActivityResult function is as follows.

In the parent Activity class, override the `onActivityResult()` method and even override the same in the Fragment class and call as the following code.

In the parent class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dualPane);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In the child class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // In fragment class callback
}
```